# Сложить числа кратные 5 и произведение положительных чисел JS

Tags: javascript, html

Сложить числа кратные 5 и вычислить произведение положительных чисел. Ввод чисел должен быть завершен при наборе числа 0. Числа вывести в документ в виде нумерованного списка а результаты вычислений оформить в виде таблицы.

Мои наработки, но не работает, поясните? Тапками не кидайтесь, пожалуйста.

```js
 <script>
 function suma(){
 var sum = 0;
 var pro = 0;
 while (x != 0){
 var x = prompt("введите число:",'');
 if ( x = 5) {sum += sum;}
 if (x > 0) {pro *= x;}
 } 
 alert("Сумма чисел, кратных 5: " + sum + "Произведение положительных чисел" + pro);}
 </script>
```

Comment: Что именно не работает?

Comment: @Suvitruf если делать без второго условия, где надо произведение делать, то ответ выводит такой: типа ввожу 2, еще 2, потом 0, чтобы прекратить цикл. И тут выводит ответ 0220. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У вас `pro` изначально равно `0`. При произведение всегда будет `0`.
2. `x = 5` - это присвоение, а не сравнение. Должно быть `===`.
3. `x === 5` проверяет на равенство. Чтоб проверить кратно ли `5`, нужно проверять, что остаток от деления на `5` будет равен `0`.
4. `prompt` возвращает строку, нужно приводить к числу.

```js
function suma(){
 var sum = 0;
 var pro = 1;
        var x = 1;
 while (x !== 0){
   x = parseInt(prompt("введите число:",''));
   if ( x % 5 === 0) {sum += x;}
   if (x > 0) {pro *= x;}
 } 
 alert("Сумма чисел, кратных 5: " + sum + ". Произведение положительных чисел" + pro);
}

suma();
```

Comment: Что-то ступил, и правда) Спасибо, добрый человек.